# restart running command windows

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I am developing applications using Gulp, with a Gulp filewatcher. This Gulp build reloads browsers as changes happen after compiling those changes. It does not, however, find new files added to directories.

If I want to load those new files I need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and then type <kbd>Y</kbd> to stop Gulp, after wich I have to run that command to watch the files again.

I wondered if there was a way to restart the command with a shortkey without needing to restart it the way I did. I use those commands for testing, bundling, exporting etc. too and would like to know a way to do this.

If not, is there a way to tell windows not to ask confirmation (so I dont have to type the <kbd>Y</kbd> every time after stopping a command), right now windows tells me `^CTerminate bath job (Y/N)?`, however the batch job already stopped right after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>N</kbd> still stops the process.